# javascript: Save functions with variable arguments in an array

Tags: javascript

This might have been asked several times, but I don't find it. The following code does - of course - not what it obviously intends:

```
var arr = [];
var count = 10;

var funct = function() { console.log("count when called: ", count); };


while (count--) {

  arr.push(funct);
}


for (i in arr) {
  arr[i]();
}
```

I got logged -1 in each for loop, because the function accesses the count value of the environment in which it was created. and count has the -1 value after the while loop.

What I need is something like passing an argument to the creation of the function. Any hints?

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dqnthjf0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to have a parameter, and then return a function that will make use of that parameter so it can be executed later. Something like this should work:

```js
var arr = [];
var count = 10;

var funct = function(c) { 
  return function() {console.log("count when called: ", c);} 
};


while (count--) {
  arr.push( funct(count) );
}


for (i in arr) {
  arr[i]();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to wrap the function `funct` within a second closure in order to create a local version of the variable count.

For example:

```
var arr = [];
var count = 10;

var funct = function () {
  var currentCount = count;
  return function() { console.log("count when called: ", currentCount); };
}


while (count--) {
  arr.push(funct());
}


for (i in arr) {
  arr[i]();
}
```

Output:

```
count when called:  9
count when called:  8
count when called:  7
count when called:  6
count when called:  5
count when called:  4
count when called:  3
count when called:  2
count when called:  1
count when called:  0
```

JSFIDDLE: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gwswjtug/

Open the console to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

Use closures - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

```
var arr = [];
var count = 10;

var funct = function(i) { 
    return function() {
        console.log("count when called: ", i); 
    }
}


while (count--) {
    arr.push(funct(count));
}


arr.forEach(function(fn) {
    fn();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ort1t6e2/